# How can I determine the new convex hull with a given distance to the original one?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a set of points and I have learned to use `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` to get the boundary of the points. And I tried to use the attributes `hull.equations` to find out the lines which form the convex hull.
[current convex hull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkvMg.png)

The next step for me is that I need to find out a way to get the points with a given distance to the current convex hull. Or a direct way to know the new convex hull of these points. For example, let's say the incremental distance to the current convex hull is `d`, I need to find out the new points, or find out the new convex hull directly. Thus, I could know the incremental area as a function of the distance `d`.
I have read the user guide of `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`, but I am sorry I am not experienced in programming and can not think about a solution. Please give me guides.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937076/distance-to-convexhull

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That is useful and I have already used that for computing the distance. But what I need is the new convex hull or only the points at the given distance. It seems to be somehow a different problem.